# Convert field "type" from 'int' to a string in a SQL database

Tags: sql, node.js, mariadb

## Problem:

I have a dog table like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE dog (type SMALLINT, ...);
```

Let me say that I want to retrieve rows from this table and convert this type to a string with semantics, like this:

```
[{id: 1, type: 'brown'}, {id: 2, type: 'choco'}, ...]
```

Instead of `[{id: 1, type : 0}, {id: 1, type : 999}]`

### **Solution 1:**

Create another table like

```
CREATE TABLE dog_type (type SMALLINT, type_s string, ...);
```

**Cons**: Join every time I need to select. Very unpleasant way.

### **Solution 2:**

Application deals with the problem:

**Cons**: Everytime that I retrieve this information I need to `".map()"` the rows.

### **Solution 3:**

Just declare the type as a string in the main table.

**Cons**: So much wasted space.

#### More info:

MariaDB serving a `nodeJS + ORM`

Any ideas? Or which one would you choose and why?

Comment: You've already mentioned three possible solutions. What kind of solution are you looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend doing Solution 1 (create an enumeration table) and then creating a SQL View that performs the join for you. This way, you'd be able to keep table `dog` intact and still be able to just write simple `select` statements against your new view to get semantic results.

Comment: Yeah, if no one gives me an ""out of the box"" solution I would do that. Ty for your answer Adil!

Answer (score 0):

If you've got a table containing Dogs and each of those Dogs has a Type which is one of a limited number of values (the examples you've given sound more like dog colours than types, but that's up to you), then a related table for Dog Types is the way to go.

The "con" you mention of having to "join every time I need to select" suggests a lack of understanding of how relational databases work. Unless you plan on only having one table in your entire database, table joins are almost inevitable, and are perfectly normal. If you create a primary key column in your Dog Type table and a foreign key column in your Dog table, this should be a trivial matter.

You haven't made any mention of how you're accessing the data - are you writing  a web application to retrieve the data? Are you connecting to it in a client application? It's very possible that whatever front end you're using will be designed to handle tables joined using foreign keys and there would be no extra effort required on your part at all.

Comment: Let's just say I have a view + node backed + orm retrieving the data.
The thing is I dont want to do a explicit SQL statement, but instead set  the ORM to work for me. Of course I can create a view or even a sql function, but is that the way to go for a problem that simple?
Ty for your answer Philip.

Comment: If you're using an ORM I would have thought this would be really simple to do with an enumeration table joined with a foreign key. I use .NET's Entity Framework (an ORM) all the time, and using that in your case would mean I'd just have to write code something like `Dog.DogType` to get the type.

Answer (score 0):

One option is a case statement perhaps in a VIEW:

```
DECLARE @dog TABLE ([type] SMALLINT, id int)
INSERT INTO @dog ([type], id)
VALUES (1,1), (1,2)
--just as an example table

SELECT [type]
      ,CASE WHEN id = 1 THEN 'brown'
            WHEN id = 2 THEN 'choco'        
       END AS [Fur Color]
 FROM @dog
```

But of course you cannot do an update statement, you have to edit the View to change values.

Comment: Ty for your answer Zorkolot!